# How would I create a Bash script that moves files?

Tags: bash, shell

So, I have 209 text files (numbered 0-208.txt) that I want to move from the directory "data" to "query".

I wrote this simple bash script, but it keeps giving me an error:

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=0
while [$counter -le 209]
do
  mv /data/$counter.txt /query
  ((counter++))
done
```

It gives me the error message:

```
generate_all_predictions.bash: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token '$'\r''
'enerate_all_predictions.bash: line 6: ' ((counter++))
```

Shouldn't the code I have just loop through /data and move all the text files into /query?

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) just suggests adding a space before and after the square brackets

Comment: your script works fine on my bash if I add spaces in the while condition.  A simpler solution is `for((i=0;i<209;i++)) ; do  mv /data/$i.txt /query ; done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least two syntax errors:

1. [A carriage return somewhere in your code.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49621678/96588) Fix by running the script through `unix2dos`.
2. `[$counter -le 209]` needs to be `[ "$counter" -le 209 ]` - the whitespace is crucial because `[` is actually a command, not just syntax like in many other languages.

You also have a logical error, because `-le` means "less than *or equal"*,so the script will try to move file 209 as well.

Since your file list is relatively small you can also use `mv /data/{0..208}.txt /query` to move everything in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a carriage return after `$`.

What text editor did you use? Did you create the script in a Windows editor?

Removing the carriage return and including spaces within the brackets as others have mentioned should get the script to work.

Answer (score 0):

Since according to your query, the numbers 0 and 208 are fixed, how about

```
 mv /data/{0..208}.txt /query
```